# ruby on rails string issue

Tags: ruby, string

I've defined a method like so:

```
def users_followers
  if current_user == @user
    "People you're following"
  else
    "People "
    your_page(@user).chomp("Page")
    " following"
  end
end
```

I'm having trouble with the second part. All I am seeing is the word `" following"`. Could you please help me with the best way to solve this?

In fact, it leaves out the space before 'following', which I need to keep.

Comment: Ruby doesn't know you want to join the three strings, you have to tell it to do so. Typically we'd use `+` or `Array.join` or interpolate into a string.

Answer (score 4):

That's because in your else, you have three statements, of which the last one is being returned. Concatenate them together:

```
def users_followers
  if current_user == @user
    "People you're following"
  else
    "People " +
    your_page(@user).chomp("Page") +
    " following"
   end
 end
```

Comment: or "People #{your_page(@user).chomp('Page')} following"

Comment: Thanks for all you answers! Works fine now, with your help.

Answer (score 4):

The method will return the results of the last statement.  In the `else` block of that method that would be the statement `" following"`.  Since the results of the preceding lines of that section aren't assigned anywhere the results get ignored.

You can use string interpolation to create a single string to return:

```
"People #{your_page(@user).chomp("Page")} following"
```